# Amazon S3: encryption speed and keys

Tags: amazon-s3, encryption

I have couple theoretical questions about Amazon S3

1. I need to encrypt all my files. What encryption speed Amazon provide for S3?
2. After encryption Amazon gives my key for file (or files package), it is possible to expire that key after one download? Or should I encrypt file again and get a new key.

Thank you!

Comment: 1. Fast? 2. I'm not aware of any such offering. Read the docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/serv-side-encryption.html

Answer (score 0):

seems like what you want to do is generate a signed URL with an expiration time. See [Share an Object with Others](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)